# implemented PIA interface has a callback, and no definition can be found

Tags: c#, com, office-interop

I am implementing the [UCCollaborationLib.IContactManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/UCCollaborationLib.IContactManager) interface, as explained in [Integrating IM applications with Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx).

I am doing it in C# as a COM+ object.

I am now at the point where Office is invoking the Lookup method from the IContactManager, but now I have to call the callback.

The method signature is:

```
[DispId(1610743810)]
AsynchronousOperation Lookup(string _lookupString, object _contactsAndGroupsCallback = null, object _state = Type.Missing);
```

And calling _contactsAndGroupsCallback.GetType().Name in the method returns __ComObject

What should I cast the callback to in order to be able to invoke it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the trick is in the name. I went through all members listed in the assembly, and there is one called _IContactsAndGroupsCallback

I cast the object I got in the method call to that, and the invocation worked. Go MS documentation!

Comment: I also stuck at same issue. Could you please share, how you have achieved the solution of this issue?

Comment: I cast the _contactsAndGroupsCallback object as an _IContactsAndGroupsCallback class, which was generated by Visual Studio as part of the importing of the IContactManager interface

Comment: I am working on events. The events of IM client to outlook are not working with Outlook 2013. Could you please help to resolve this issue? Events: OnStateChanged, OnContactInformationChanged etc

Comment: Sorry @KrishPS, I also had issues with it "just not working", ultimately leading me to abandon the attempt at integration.